# JQuery printElement prints the whole page in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, html, printing

I am using [jQuery printElement](https://github.com/erikzaadi/jQueryPlugins/wiki/jQuery.printElement) in order to print the content of a div.

It's working perfectly on Safari, Chrome and Firefox but when I try with Internet Explorer (all versions), it prints the whole page instead of the div only. Why is that? What can I do?

Here's the code used to print :

```
$('.print_button').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.details').find('.div_to_print').printElement({
            pageTitle: '...',
            overrideElementCSS: [
                '<?php echo stylesheet_path("print.css"); ?>'
            ]
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using simply CSS:

```
@media print {
      .element-not-to-print {
          display: none;
      }
}
```

OR

```
@media print {
      .element-not-to-print {
          visibility: hidden;
      }
}
```

Support for Media Queries is **IE9+** : http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries

**For IE7 and IE8 use** check [this article](http://cssmatter.com/blog/ie7-and-ie8-support-for-css3-media-query/). Or just go straight to the point by adding [this JavaScript file](https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) to your project and continue using the good old Media Queries that will not kill your performance like jQuery.