# printing only the selected data

Tags: php, html, printing

I am submitting the php form in the same page after displaying the data, i want to print it. I am able to do this. But i want to print only the resulted data which am displaying in a table.

Here is my page

```
<?php

include ("include/dbconnect.php");
include ("include/format.inc.php");

?>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
window.print();
}
</script>
<script src="htmlDatePicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="htmlDatePicker.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script type="text/javascript"><!--
        var today = new Date();

        DisablePast = false;
        range_start = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),8);
        range_end = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),5);
    --></script>


<?php
include ("include/header.inc.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$date1 = $_POST['SelectedDate1'];
$date2 = $_POST['SelectedDate1'];

echo $date1;
echo $date2;

$sql = "select * from addressbook where lindate between '".$date1."' AND '".$date2."' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());


    echo '<table width="90%" align="center" cellpadding="0" border="0">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo '<tr><td>' .$row['firstname']. $row['lastname']. '</td>';
echo '<td>' .$row['address']. '</td>';
echo '<td>' .$row['mobile']. '</td>';
echo '<td>' .$row['email']. '</td>';
echo '<td>' .$row['lindate']. '</td>';
echo '<td>' .$row['lintime']. '</td>';
echo '<td>' .$row['louttime']. '</td>';
echo '<td>' .$row['login']. '</td></tr>';   

}
echo '</table>';

echo '<button onclick="myFunction()">Print this page</button>';
}
?>




<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">
Select Date Range:<br />

<input type="text" placeholder="Click me!" name="SelectedDate1" id="SelectedDate" readonly onClick="GetDate(this);">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; TO &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<input type="text" placeholder="Click me!" name="SelectedDate2" id="SelectedDate" readonly onClick="GetDate(this);">



<input type="submit" name="submit" value="VIEW DATA" />
</form>

<?php include ("include/footer.inc.php");?>
```

here i want to select only the data within the table. Please suggest me how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is printed can be easily controlled via a print style sheet. Within the print stylesheet you can use display: none; on elements or blocks such as headers, footers, menus etc. This way only the content you want to be printed will be sent to the printer.

This article should get you going with creating the print stylesheet:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank to you. It helped me a lot. And my problem is resolved. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, glad this helped. It is possible to use javascript to send specific content to the printer but I've found that approach to be flakey between various browsers. Print stylesheets are certainly my preferred approach.

Comment: What about older IE support? Does the article deal with it? Or maybe you should use https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/?

Answer (score 0):

Place the table in a `div` then use jquery to print:  `$("mailcontent").printElement();`

Comment: Don't know personally, but it seems this has issues with IE?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449955/jquery-printelement-prints-the-whole-page-in-internet-explorer